# How to get JSON object in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

```
var data =  '[{"type":"product","id":1,"label":"Size","placeholder":"Select Size","description":"","defaultValue"
:{"text":"Size30","price":"20"},"choices":[{"text":"Size30","price":"20","isSelected":"true"},{"text"
:"Size32","price":"22","isSelected":false},{"text":"Size34","price":"28","isSelected":false}],"conditionalLogic"
:""},{"type":"product","id":2,"label":"Color","placeholder":"Select Color","description":"","defaultValue"
:{"text":"Black","price":"10"},"choices":[{"text":"Black","price":"10","isSelected":"true"},{"text"
:"Green","price":"22","isSelected":false},{"text":"Red","price":"28","isSelected":false}],"conditionalLogic"
:""},{"type":"product","id":3,"label":"Rise","placeholder":"Select Rise","description":"","defaultValue"
:{"text":"Low","price":"8"},"choices":[{"text":"High","price":"12","isSelected":"true"},{"text"
:"Low","price":"8","isSelected":false}],"conditionalLogic"
:""}]';
```

Here I have posted my JSON data. I want to get all the defaultValue in JSON/Array format. My output should be like-

```
 defaultValues:['Size30','Black','Low']
```

How to manage that in the foreach loop?

my code :

```
var otherSelectedOption;
angular.forEach(data, function(optionValue, optionKey) {
      if (optionValue.defaultValue.text) {
          otherSelectedOption = (optionValue.defaultValue.text);
      }
      selectedOption = {defaultValues: otherSelectedOption};
      console.log(selectedOption);          
});
```

Comment: `data` ===> `JSON.parse(data)` ...... i.e, `angular.forEach(JSON.parse(data),`

Comment: `var r = JSON.parse(data).map(x=>x.defaultValues)`

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is not valid, since objects are not separated by comma `,`

Suppose this is the JSON

```
var obj = '[{"type":"product","id":1,"label":"Size","placeholder":"Select Size","description":"","defaultValue"
:{"text":"Size30","price":"20"},"choices":[{"text":"Size30","price":"20","isSelected":"true"},{"text"
:"Size32","price":"22","isSelected":false},{"text":"Size34","price":"28","isSelected":false}],"conditionalLogic"
:""},{"type":"product","id":2,"label":"Color","placeholder":"Select Color","description":"","defaultValue"
:{"text":"Black","price":"10"},"choices":[{"text":"Black","price":"10","isSelected":"true"},{"text"
:"Green","price":"22","isSelected":false},{"text":"Red","price":"28","isSelected":false}],"conditionalLogic"
:""},{"type":"product","id":3,"label":"Rise","placeholder":"Select Rise","description":"","defaultValue"
:{"text":"Low","price":"8"},"choices":[{"text":"High","price":"12","isSelected":"true"},{"text"
:"Low","price":"8","isSelected":false}],"conditionalLogic"
:""}]';
```

try

```
var arr = JSON.parse(obj).map( function(item){
   return item.defaultValue;
});
```

Comment: @Moran sorry I am not able to open this link, can you share a fiddle instead? Also, what is it about?

Comment: no worries , it's the some code you wrote in a runnable manner :)